# Using iPhone battery port to get a little charge for my device

Tags: iphone

I am working on an emergency device that is rather tiny and needs a small amount of electricity when in use.

I wanted to have an app on the iPhone that would Bluetooth communicate with the device but I wanted to keep the product small by getting the electricity from the Apple battery by plugging in a jack from my device into the iPhone charging port.

Would this work?

Comment: The iPhone will charge the Apple Pencil, but it may need to 'recognize' it. Other devices might be ignored?

Comment: JoeTaxpayer, YOU ARE BRILLIANT!    I have asked this question in many forums and you are the very first to give me such a valuable answer.  I thank you, thank you, thank you.

Comment: This doesn't mean it will work for other devices as well, though.

Comment: @Alex - LOL thanks. Patrix - to a scientist or engineer, it wasn't an answer, (thus the comment) but more like a clue. Evidence, an Apple device, that can use the port to charge. More important, not the iPad Pro, which the pencil was designed for, but an iPhone that wasn't really expecting it.